# DateTime object transformed to string type after form POST

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime, post, doctrine-orm

I have a form to edit a `News` entity. Here it is:

```
<form action="{{path('validate_news', {'id': news.id})}}" method="POST" >
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="Text" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Text</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <textarea name = "text" type="text" class="form-control" id="text" aria-describedby="textHelp" placeholder="{{news.text|e}}"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input name = "startDate" type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate" aria-describedby="startDate" placeholder="{{news.startDate|date('d-m-Y')}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="expireDate" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Expire Date</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input name = "expireDate" type="date" class="form-control" id="expireDate" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="{{news.expireDate|date('d-m-Y')}}">
    </div>
   </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There is the controller for the `validate_news` route, activated when the user clicks the Submit button:

```
/**
* @Route("/validateNews/{id}", name = "validate_news")
* @Method("POST")
**/
public function validateNewsAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:News');
    $news = $repository->findOneById($id);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $text = $request->get('text');
        $startDate = new \DateTime();
        $startDate = $request->get('startDate');
        $expireDate = new \DateTime();
        $expireDate = $request->get('expireDate');
    }

    $news->setText($text);
    $news->setStartDate($startDate);
    $news->setexpireDate($expireDate);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($news);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->render("AppBundle:Default:editNewsSuccess.html.twig", array ('news' => $news));

}
```

The `startDate` and `expireDate` properties are defined as `datetime`.

When I try to flush the `News` object, I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in DateTimeType.php line 53:
Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

Launching a `var_dump` on `$startDate` in the controller I can see that it has a `string` type. But in the form I defined it as a `datetime`.

Why is this happening on `POST` call?

Comment: Cause you are getting string value from your form. You need to set a DateTime object to your entity. Try like that `$startDate = new \DateTime($request->get('startDate'));`

Comment: @MertÖksüz Thanks, it worked! In my example I first created a DateTime object, and then I gave it the form value. Your method is correct.

Comment: i wroted as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you are getting string value from your form. You need to set a DateTime object to your entity.

Try like that

```
$startDate = new \DateTime($request->get('startDate'));
```